# Is there any limit for multiple likes at once by Instagram iOS API

Tags: instagram

In my iOS app that using Instagram API and frequently Likes selected photos within a for loop.
I'm  using this API https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/%@/likes. It works fine for all initial likes and then suddenly throws response error as:

```
 meta = {
        code = 400;
        "error_message" = "you cannot like this media";
        "error_type" = APINotAllowedError;
    };
```

There is no pattern this error follows. Please let me know if there is any limit likes/hour or likes/min etc. or some kind of blocking form Instagram after frequent api hits.

Comment: First page of ig documentation says: `Do not abuse the API. Too many requests too quickly will get your access turned off` http://instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Is there any solution to this? like by adding delay in api calls.

Comment: That sounds like a question for Instagram...